# Custom strtoi function compile time issue

Tags: c++, c++11, compile-time-constant

I am trying to implement a very simple `strtoi` function. It works fine when when the passed arguments are dynamically created (case 2 below). However, if the char is created by `char[]` which is allocated during compile time, I get a constant value on `len` because of `std::strlen(ch)` which messes up my logic, and I can't find a solution for this.

```
 int strtoi(char* ch)
 {   
  int sum {0};
  int len = static_cast<int>(std::strlen(ch));
  int skipLast = static_cast<int>(static_cast<int>(ch[0]) == 45);

  //Integer Method
  for(int i = len - 1; i >= 0 + skipLast; i--)
  {
    if(static_cast<int>(ch[i]) < 48 || static_cast<int>(ch[i]) > 57)
      return 0;
    sum += (ch[i]-48) * std::pow(10,i-skipLast);
  }

   sum = skipLast == 1 ? -sum : sum;
   return sum;
 }

int main()
{
  char pos[3] {'1','2','3'};
  std::cout << strtoi(pos) << std::endl;
  char neg[4] {'-','1','2','3'};
  std::cout << strtoi(neg) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Returns: `0` and `-123`. The `len` variable in my function doesn't get the expected value for the first call and I assume it is because `neg[4]` allocates more memory then `pos[3]`. However, for the second case:

```
int main()
{
  char* pos;
  pos = new char[3] {'1','2','3'};
  std::cout << strtoi(pos) << std::endl;
  char* neg;
  neg = new char[4] {'-','1','2','3'};
  std::cout << strtoi(neg) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Returns `123`, `-123`. The expected result.
I guess this happens because in the first case the compiler is allocating memory for the function and its argument according to the `char[4]` array. Is this correct?
How does it works for the second case, how is the compiler allocating memory to the function for the dynamic variables?
And what is a possible solution to make the function work for both cases?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `static_cast<int>(static_cast<int>(ch[0]) == 45)` is a really complicated way of saying `ch[0] == '-'`. I also recommend you learn to use [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) and `ch[i]-'0'` instead. And generally stop using [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Comment: Also note that [`std::pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) is a *floating point* function, which brings all the problems that comes from handling floating point values (like rounding errors). There are other way to use posers of ten, for example by initializing an integer variable suitably, and then multiply or divide it by `10` each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strlen` requires that the string be null terminated, like this:

```
char* pos = new char[4] {'1','2','3','\0'};
std::cout << strlen(pos) << "\n";  // Shows "3"
```

There is a short hand for adding this null terminator:

```
const char[] pos = "123";
std::cout << strlen(pos) << "\n";  // Shows "3"
std::cout << sizeof(pot) << "\n";  // Shows "4"
```

I used an array type for pos just to illustrate it is really 4 characters; you could use `const char*` instead (actually that would be typical) but then the `sizeof` line wouldn't work.

Note that if you allocate a string literal like this then you cannot use `delete` on it later, whereas you can (and should) use `delete` if you use `new`, or `delete[]` for arrays.

Comment: `char* pos = new char[3] {'1','2','3','\0'};` is not correct.

Comment: @anastaciu You are right, thanks for pointing that out. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The problems you have is that you forget that `char` strings in C++ are really called ***null-terminated*** byte strings.

That *null-terminator* is what all standard string functions (like `std::strlen`) will look for to know where the string ends.

Your strings are *not* null-terminated, therefore passing them to e.g. `std::strlen` will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as they go out of bounds of the arrays or allocated memory, looking for this non-existing null-terminator.

To solve that problem you need to make sure that all strings are null-terminated:

```
// will create pos as an array of *four* characters, the last being the null-terminator
char pos[] = "123";
```

Answer (score 3):

I have modified your code as below:

```
int strtoi(char* ch, int len)
{
    int sum{ 0 };
    //int len = (std::strlen(ch));
    int skipLast = static_cast<int>(static_cast<int>(ch[0]) == 45);

    //Integer Method
    for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0 + skipLast; i--)
    {
        if (static_cast<int>(ch[i]) < 48 || static_cast<int>(ch[i]) > 57)
            return 0;
        sum += (ch[i] - 48) * std::pow(10, i - skipLast);
    }

    sum = skipLast == 1 ? -sum : sum;
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    char pos[3]{ '1','2','3' };
    std::cout << strtoi(pos, 3) << std::endl;
    char neg[4]{ '-','1','2','3' };
    std::cout << strtoi(neg, 4) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`strtoi` was not able to calculate the array length inside a function. You have to pass it with an array pointer as there is no '\0' character.
That's why when you pass an array to function you have to pass the array size or length as well.

Output of above-modified code:

> 321
>
> -321